# L3 cache disabled in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-11.04

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 64bit .. After checking my CPU cache it shows that 3MB cache is disabled. see below :

```
$ sudo lshw 

  description: Notebook
    product: SATELLITE C660 (PSC1SE-00G009AR)
    vendor: TOSHIBA
    version: PSC1SE-00G009AR
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ sku=PSC1SE-00G009AR uuid=EF8F3D08-7C40-11E0-A5EC-B870F463470C
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 64KiB
             capacity: 64KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
        *-cache:2 DISABLED
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: internal unified
```

I found that *-cache:2 is disabled .

How can i enable CPU 3MB cache ?

```
fadi@fadi:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
p    hysical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4589.39
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4589.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4589.53
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4589.55
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Was that cache shown as enabled in a previous version of Ubuntu? Is it shown as enabled in another operating system?

Comment: Are you sure lshw isn't lying to you?

Answer (score 0):

CPU cache are very low-level, you should check at least in your BIOS.

After Googling around for *[lshw cache disabled](http://www.google.it/search?q=lshw%20cache%20disabled)*, it seems a common problem with usually new CPUs, and they get fixed upstream.

Probably you don't need to get worried about it.

Comment: Added my cpuinfo , check it out